# What mobile phones with NFC have full support of Mifare Classic (1K & 4K) cards?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare, hce

Google has stopped supporting such tags in the latest Nexus 4, but what phones still have possibility of reading\writing Mifare Classic cards? Especially interested in hi-end models with powerful processors.

Also could anyone provide some inforamtion on emulating such nfc tags with your phone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157067/which-android-phones-support-mifare-classic-nfc-tags/157069#157069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that Google stopped support for MIFARE Classic. Instead licensing issues prevent Broadcom to integrate MIFARE Classic reader technology (property of NXP) into their NFC chipsets. Thus, any NFC device with a non-NXP NFC chipset (which is pretty much every new Samsung device, the new Nexus 7, and several more) will not support MIFARE Classic.

Regarding emulation: Emulating MIFARE Classic with a phone is only possible if the secure element in the phone supports MIFARE Classic card technology. Most secure element manufacturers have licensed MIFARE CLassic card technology and offer it in their secure elements.